# Manejar Login Failed imap-tools

Tags: python-3.x, imap

Tengo una lista de 10 correos para obtener sus Attachments pero, en ocasiones cambian los passwords por seguridad, sin embargo no todos los cambian al mismo tiempo, me gustaria poder validar con un exception, y que, en caso de login fallido el script no se rompa, pase al siguiente email, estaba intentando hacer el script de 1 solo hilo por el momento hasta lograr validar la parte del exception.

```
from imap_tools import MailBox, AND

server = 'outlook.office365.com'
user = 'primerMail@hotmail.com'
password = 'xxxxx'

mb = MailBox(server).login(user,password)
```

Y el error obtenido cuando es password mal es este:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\oficina\Documents\PycharmProjects\Outlook\main.py", line 8, in <module>
    mb.login(user,password)
  File "C:\Users\oficina\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\imap_tools\mailbox.py", line 64, in login
    check_command_status(login_result, MailboxLoginError)
  File "C:\Users\oficina\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\imap_tools\utils.py", line 46, in check_command_status
    raise exception(command_result=command_result, expected=expected)
imap_tools.errors.MailboxLoginError: Response status "OK" expected, but "NO" received. Data: [b'LOGIN failed.']
```

Soy un poco nuevo en python y no se como manejar esos errores.
Gracias!

Comment: `try:
    mb = MailBox(server).login(user,password)
except:
    # Fallo el login`